# What's the meaning of "You better take this"?

Tags: grammar, expression-choice, adverb-position

My mother tongue is Hindi. I was watching an English movie when I came across the below sentence. Although it is a dual language movie and that helps me to understand English and improve my vocabulary, there is one sentence that I cannot understand.

And after searching on Google, now I am here.

What's the difference between:

> You better take this.

and:

> You take this.

Comment: Downvoting for failure to provide context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You better take this" is a common colloquial form of "You'd better take this", i.e. "You had better take this".

"Had better" is an idiom which functions as a modal auxiliary, meaning something like "should" or "need to". Literally it means something like "It would be better if you took this", but it is not really analysable in modern English.

Answer (score 2):

> You better take this.

This means, "You had better take this."  In English, we use contractions.  When we say, "You had," we simply say, "You'd."  However, the way the "d" in "you'd" sounds when said against the "b" in "better," makes it almost inaudible.  As a result, many English speakers end up saying and even writing, "You better."

What it actually means is: "You ought to take this," or, "It would behoove you to take this."

> You take this.

This isn't something people would generally say as a sentence.  We don't say "you" beforehand.  When using the imperative voice, we simply say, "Take this."  Occasionally, people will add an enunciated "you" before the imperative of a verb, but it's not standard fare.  It's only done to make some kind of special emphasis.

It would be said like this in the present indicative.  In the present indicative, though, it wouldn't be telling someone to take it.

Comment: While “You take this.” as a standalone sentence with no context would be rare and non-idiomatic, it’s possible for “you take” to appear in a sentence; e.g., “You take too much time” or “You take your coffee black, right?” or “I’ve discovered that you take money from the cash box when nobody’s looking.”  Or in a list with other people and objects, with indication by gesture.  Alice said “I’ll take this”, picking up the tent, “and you take this”, handing the bag of food to Bob.

Answer (score 0):

> you better take this

is advise.

> you take this

is an order.

The difference has nothing to do with the word 'had'.  It's whether or not someone who has the authority to give you orders is giving you a choice here.

Better indicates an opinion is being expressed.  Without it, you are being told what to do.

Comment: No. This is plain wrong. It is possible that "You better" is now being reanalysed as something other than a rapid version of "You'd better", but even if it is, it has nothing to do with authority. _You('d) better take this_ is better contrasted with _you can take this_, not with _you take this_, which is indeed usually an order.

Comment: You can say that.  But you better not.

Comment: *"Take this"* is a simple and direct order.  *"You take this"* - the pronoun softens the order and makes it less brusque.

Comment: I don't think pronoun means what you think it means.

Comment: @Dan It might soften it but it doesn't soften it much. As far as I'm concerned they're both potentially abrupt, it would depend on the tone of voice.

Comment: @BoldBen - Agreed.  Tone is obviously important.  But also, usually, the fewer words used, the more imperative/peremptory the command.

Answer (score -1):

Using the word "you" before the word "better" seems to imply that the person being spoken to needs to be directed in some particular way. Thus doing away with the persons ability to choose to do it or not. It is a challenge to do whatever needs to be done according to the one speaking or receive some sort of reprimand. It is threatening (to some) and possibly dis respective as well. It is or can be offensive in that it almost seems to assume that the person being spoken to does not have the sense necessary to make a right decision and so, they need (my)guidance.

Comment: I agree that “You better” (or “You’d better”) carries an implicit threat, and I’m surprised that none of the other answers mentioned that (although Colin’s hints at it).   But the rest of your answer is word soup.   “You better” *can* be advice (“You’d better take your umbrella today; the forecast calls for rain.”), but, as stated in other answers, it is more often an instruction / command / order given by somebody in authority.